# Using ValidationMessages bundle with Spring Webflow Validation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow-2

How do I wire up a Spring ValidationMessages bundle in a custom Webflow [Validator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/html/ch05s10.html) class?  I have a validator implemented and working:

```
public void validateBusinessReferences(BusinessReferencesViewDao businessReferences, Errors errors) {
    if (somecondition())) {
        errors.rejectValue("name", "validation.message123", "This field is bad.");
    }
}
```

But instead of the message from the ValidationMessages.properties file, I get the fallback default of `This field is bad.`

All my other messages and validations work fine - it's just this custom validator/custom message scenario that's failing.   I suspect a Spring configuration problem of some kind but I can't isolate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved - I was missing a step.   In order to use a properties bundle you need to use a MessageResolver and call it like so:

```
MessageResolver messageResolver = new MessageBuilder().error().source(source).code("validation.message.property.here").defaultText(errorMessage).build();
messageResolver.resolveMessage(messageSource, Locale.ENGLISH);
return messageResolver;
```

Where your messageSource is your Spring bean with your message properties bundles, defined in your application context:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>messages</value>
            <value>ValidationMessages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Documentation on MessageResolver is [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/binding/message/MessageResolver.html).

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the `ValidationMessages.properties` is for customizing messages when using JSR-303 style annotations. Since your're not using those here - rather you're using a custom validator method and calling `errors.rejectValue` directly, you should place your messages in the standard `messages.properties` file. In webflow, this file is flow specific and lives alongside the flow definition XML file in the same folder.

Comment: Yes, I had tried several different ways of doing this.   I finally got it straightened out using MessageResolver.   Spring documentation is not very clear on the point of which message file is "proper" for these messages and they could probably go in either.   I wound up putting both of them in my message source bean and also added the important step of actually calling resolveMessage() which resolves the message against the message source.   I wasn't doing that before.  (Oops.)